# AngularJS Scope don't call elements

Tags: arrays, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi guys this exercise with scopes don't run,

View:

```
<body ng-controller="marcasController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in marcas">
      {{todo.nombre}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tipo in todo.modelo">{{tipo.nombre}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('marcasController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.marcas = 
  [{
  "marcas": [
    {
      "marca": "Chevrolet",
      "modelo": [
        {
          "nombre": "Aveo",
          "image": "images/aveo.jpg",
          "modelo": "2000-2014",
          "tab": "aveo"
        },
        {
        "nombre": "Captiva",
        "image": "images/captiva.jpg",
        "modelo": "2000-2014",
        "tab": "captiva"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}];
  }])
```

### [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IyetD4ezxN4Uc8iZ68hT?p=preview)

please how use scopes to call objects

Comment: you should add the relevant code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Given that data structure you should be doing it like this:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in marcas[0].marcas">
      {{todo.marca}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tipo in todo.modelo">{{tipo.nombre}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

## [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/56qzqpP96V77wcWY3sxP?p=preview)

Notice that `$scope.marcas` is an `Array` of objects that contains just one element, that element has only one attribute: `marcas` which is another Array...

Maybe you wanted that data structure to be like this instead:

```
  $scope.marcas =[
    {
      "marca": "Chevrolet",
      "modelo": [
        {
          "nombre": "Aveo",
          "image": "images/aveo.jpg",
          "modelo": "2000-2014",
          "tab": "aveo"
        },
        {
        "nombre": "Captiva",
        "image": "images/captiva.jpg",
        "modelo": "2000-2014",
        "tab": "captiva"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

In that case, the correct syntax for your view would be:

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="todo in marcas">
      {{todo.marca}}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tipo in todo.modelo">{{tipo.nombre}}</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

## [Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/IFgpQkeELwZ5seuB9JKO?p=preview)

Comment: hi, excuseme for the late, but how repet marcas and how acces to elements in modelos this example... http://plnkr.co/edit/aFYv2ynwbwvwWbotU0iJ?p=preview
file app.js this structure is incorrect? please helme